# Limiting results to latest in django and mezzanine

Tags: python, django, django-templates, mezzanine

I have written some models in django that are displayed as sortable lists where you can add as many elements as possible in some cases this is fine but in other cases I want to restrict it to new additions only so old sections and pushed off the page when new information is added here is what I have so far it just pull all of them through I am looking to limit it to the 4 latest items in the list not sure how to go about doing this as I am new to django and mezzanine.

```
{% if page.homepage.news.all %}
    {% for news in page.homepage.news.all %}
        <div class="content">        
            <h5>{{ news.title }}</h5>
            <p>{{ news.content }}</p>
        </div>
        <hr />
    {% endfor %}  
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to this is actually quite simple when you find out bellow is the edited code that allows you to limit what is displayed. Slice works quite nice in limiting the loop to a set number or iterations. Then all you need to do is add your new post and rearrange it to the top of the list.

```
{% if page.homepage.news.all %}
    {% for news in page.homepage.news.all|slice:":4" %}
        <div class="content">
          <!-- Title -->
          <h5>{{ news.title }}</h5>
          <p>{{ news.content }}</p>
        </div>
        <hr />
    {% endfor %}  
{% endif %}
```